# Pass an object or positioned arguments to a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

It's now possible to destructure function parameters like so:

```
function add({a, b}) { return a + b; }
```

Which can be called like this:

```
add({a: 5, b: 9});
```

Is it also possible to combine that with positional arguments so it can also be called without naming the arguments. E.g.:

```
add(5, 9);
```

Comment: Does your and, or Ori Drori's Answer resolve Question? What is purpose of the pattern where a function expects either a single object parameter or multiple parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), and destructure it according to it's length.

```js
function add(...args) {
  let a, b;
  
  args.length === 1 ? ({ a, b } = args[0]) : [a, b] = args;
  
  return a + b;
};

console.log(add({a: 5, b: 9}));
console.log(add(5, 9));
```

Comment: Would this only work for functions that take more than one argument?

Comment: You can tailor it to fit your needs by changing the destructuring method according to the length of args. However, as stated by @estus in the deleted answer - "Multiple function signatures are misleading and require too much negotiation on provided arguments for no good reason".